# Checking the whole disk health from Linux, including the Windows partitions

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, uefi

I have both Ubuntu and Windows installed.
I was using Windows today and suddenly it crashed, so I rebooted and got a

Reboot and select proper Boot Device

message. I rebooted and finally got to Windows, followed by some blue screens, so I tried to switch to Ubuntu, but the `grub` menu disappeared, and I found not a single boot option in BIOS. I rebooted again, changed the boot options after they finally appeared, and booted to Linux and all is working fine for now.

I thought it was a disk issue?
If anyone knows what else could have caused the problem, please let me know.
I want to check the health of my disk, something like "chkdsk" in Windows that checks my whole disk and not only the Ubuntu system.

Again, if it seems like it's not a disk issue, please let me know.

Comment: You might want to look into the `smartmontools` where you can check the drive itself.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: Ubuntu developers do not pretend to be experts in testing and diagnosing the arcane problems that proprietary Windows installs may suffer. Test and repair Linux using Linux tools. Test and repair Windows using Windows tools.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, lots of info. And no i'm not trying to repair my Windows, im trying to troubleshoot and i know the issue, little i know. And by the way I just opened my Ubuntu today and it's very laggy, and unfortunately screen turned black and i got messages like "EXT4 fs error" and "systemd-journalId: failed to write entry, ignoring read only file system. Does that confirm it is hardware?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds very much like a hard disk/hardware issue. It's very possible your disk is failing. I'd suggest you obtain a utility from your disk manufacturer (which usually runs from a boot disk) and check whether your disk is functioning correctly.
Regarding the rest of your question, there is no tool that does what you want from within Linux, really, because of the way the NTFS filesystem works. NTFS has it's own journaling system, and it's own repair/recovery methods. NTFS is a robust filesystem that is hard to break, and not prone to issues of corruption or errors. If you modify or tamper with NTFS files from outside your Windows account, it will be detected when you restart Windows and probably force a consistency check. If Windows is shut down unexpectedly, such as from a crash or power failure, files will be left in an inconsistent state, and even Linux tools will warn you against trying to write to an inconsistent disk state, as there is a risk of overwriting or corrupting data. As the other person stated, it's best to manage Linux filesystems with Linux tools from within Linux, and manage Windows files using Windows tools from within Windows. This is all complicated by the fact that Windows is not designed as a multi-boot OS, (though it certainly works as one), and does not gracefully let other boot managers like grub control it's boot process. Of course, neither grub or Windows' boot loader are fault-tolerant, so if something changes the boot order detected, or messes up the hard disk, you're going to have problems.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, and i think what happened today confirms what you just said, its most likely hardware. I just opened my ubuntu today and it's very laggy, and unfortunately screen turned black and i got messages like "EXT4 fs error" and "systemd-journalId: failed to write entry, ignoring read only  file system. Does that confirm it is hardware?

Comment: It does not confirm it's a hardware issue, but that's the most likely scenario at this point. If you run your disk utility, (if possible) I'm sure it will show numerous failures.